# How to rebuild or clone base conda install?

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have a large conda installation that is being used by multiple users. I'm having problems with it where it seems to be getting fragile. I'd like to rebuild it from scratch. I can do a `conda list` and get a list of packages, but the dependencies will all be random. If I just run a script to install that list, I get constant messages of upgrading and downgrading versions etc.

Is there a way to create a "smart" list of my packages to do an efficient rebuild?

**EDIT**
Nehal suggested `conda list --export`. That gives me a list of the form:

```
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64    
<package>=<version>
<package>=<version>
...
```

I was able to make one like that just with just `conda list` and then `awk`, but that did have some duplicates and packages that caused errors.

Nevertheless, how do I then use this rebuild the install, rather than creating an environment as the list header says?

I tried

```
conda install $(cat packagelist | tr "\n" " ")
```

But got some inconsistencies. Could be my channel priorities?

Comment: conda list --export

Comment: @NehalJWani, added some additional info. Thanks!